# File input problem in HTML5 on Chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome, filereader

I'm trying to make a audio player in Chrome with HTML5 and Javascript. But I got an error(file not readable) at the very beginning...

Below is my HTML code:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />

    <!-- Always force latest IE rendering engine (even in intranet) & Chrome Frame
    Remove this if you use the .htaccess -->
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />

    <title>index</title>
    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <meta name="generator" content="Studio 3 http://aptana.com/" />
    <meta name="author" content="liuuzyan" />

    <!--<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0" />-->

    <!-- Replace favicon.ico & apple-touch-icon.png in the root of your domain and delete these references -->
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/apple-touch-icon.png" />

    <script src="js/jquery-1.6.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/fun.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <audio id="player" controls="controls">
        Please use Firefox/Chrome/IE9 to browse this page.
    </audio>
    <input type="file" multiple="multiple" id="fileChose" />
</body>
```

And below is my Javascript code:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $('#fileChose').change( function() {
        var fileList=this.files;
        for(var i=0;i<fileList.length;i++) {
            var reader=new FileReader();
            reader.onloaded=function(e){
                $('#player').attr('src',e.target.result)
            }
            reader.onerror=function(e){
                switch(e.target.error.code) {
                    case e.target.error.NOT_FOUND_ERR:
                            alert("file not found");
                            break;
                    case e.target.error.NOT_READABLE_ERR:
                            alert("file not readable");
                            break;
                    case e.target.error.ABORT_ERR:
                            alert("aborted");
                            break;
                    default:
                            alert('generic error?');
                }
            }
            reader.readAsDataURL(fileList[i]);
        }
    });
});
```

Can anyone help me with this problem? Thanks a lot!

Comment: I have updated the Chrome to the newest version. And the previous error code(4) was changed to 2... Really strange for me...

Comment: Problem solved. Just upload codes to server and it works fine. I think the problem is caused by the security system of Chrome with the local static html file.

Comment: yup — I believe all browsers, not just Chrome, will prevent web pages from reading files on the user’s machine. If they didn’t, it would be what professional security researchers call “a freaking enormous security hole”.

Answer (score 0):

In Chrome you can add: --allow-file-access-from-files to the Chrome command line to allow local file to be read from local HTML pages.

You can also bundle your code up as Chrome Extension and get local file access that way.

Or upload the HTML files to a Server as already mentioned.